# Azure vm provisioning and user assigned identity?

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am looking to resolve issue with trying to apply to the vm I am creating an identity using python sdk.  The code:

```
print("Creating VM " + resource_name)
compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update(
    resource_group_name,
    resource_name,
    {
        "location": "eastus",
        "storage_profile": {
            "image_reference": {
                # Image ID can be retrieved from `az sig image-version show -g $RG -r $SIG -i $IMAGE_DEFINITION -e $VERSION --query id -o tsv`
                "id": "/subscriptions/..image id"
            }
        },
        "hardware_profile": {
            "vm_size": "Standard_F8s_v2"
        },
        "os_profile": {
            "computer_name": resource_name,
            "admin_username": "adminuser",
            "admin_password": "somepassword",
            "linux_configuration": {
                "disable_password_authentication": True,
                "ssh": {
                    "public_keys": [
                        {
                            "path": "/home/adminuser/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                            # Add the public key for a key pair that can get access to SSH to the runners
                            "key_data": "ssh-rsa …"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "network_profile": {
            "network_interfaces": [
                {
                    "id": nic_result.id
                }
            ]
        },
        "identity": {
            "type": "UserAssigned",
            "user_assigned_identities": {
                "identity_id": { myidentity }
            }
        }
    }
```

The last part, identity: I found somewhere on the web, (not sure where), but it is failing with some weird set/get error when I try to use it.  The vm will create fine if I comment out the identity: block, but I need the user assigned identity.  I spent the better part of today trying to find information on the options for the begin_create_or_update and info on the identity piece, but I have had no luck.  I am looking for help on how to apply a user assigned identity with python to the vm I am creating.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

The ***Set and Get*** error is because you are declaring the identity block in a wrong way.

[image]

**If you have a existing User Assigned Identity then you can use the identity block as below:**

```
    "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "user_assigned_identities": {
            '/subscriptions/948d4068-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/ansumantest/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mi-identity' : {}
            }
```

As you can see, inside the `user_assigned_identities` it will be :

```
'User Assigned Identity ResourceID':{}
```

instead of

```
"identity_id":{'User Assigned Identity ResourceID'}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]